# Exception has been thrown by a target of an invocation error in C# program and VS2017?

Tags: c#, exception, visual-studio-2017, portable-class-library

I have a C# program that I'm using with VS2017.  When I run the app I get a simple message box, twice, with the exact message:

"Exception has been thrown by a target of an invocation error in C# program and VS2017?"

The error is happening in one of the referenced PCL projects (Portable Class Library).  I don't know which one because the message box has absolutely no other information other than the sentence above.  I am *not* getting the Exception dialog that has the rich error information like the one you see when an exception occurs in your main code.  Therefore, I can't look for the *innerException* for the actual cause, which is the main solution to diagnosing the underlying exception that is recommended in all the other Stack Overflow posts related to this problem that I found.  I can't use the *try/catch* method of trapping the error because it is occurring in during the initialization phase of the other referenced libraries and outside the scope of my code.  I know this because I put a break point on the very first line of code in my app and those two "dumb" exception message boxes pop up *before* I hit my breakpoint.

How can I find out which of the referenced libraries are causing the error?

Comment: Is it possible you are missing dependent packages? Core packages that the referenced libraries need

Comment: @Jawad - Even if it is, I still want to know how to get the InnerException dialog.